# What is the right algorithm for digitally signing in C and veryfing in PHP?

Tags: php, c, rsa, phpseclib, php-openssl

I'm trying to digitally sign files/messages in C and verify the signature in PHP.
I can verify it correctly in C, but when I try to import the signature and verify it in PHP it fails.

I'm signing the message in C using this method:

```
bool RSASign( RSA* rsa,
              const unsigned char* Msg,
              size_t MsgLen,
              unsigned char** EncMsg,
              size_t* MsgLenEnc) {
    EVP_MD_CTX* m_RSASignCtx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(privkey, rsa);
    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(m_RSASignCtx,NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL,privkey)<=0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(m_RSASignCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, NULL, MsgLenEnc) <=0) {
        return false;
    }
    *EncMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(*MsgLenEnc);
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, *EncMsg, MsgLenEnc) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(m_RSASignCtx);
    return true;
}
```

As I said, it's working fine if I try to validate this signature only in C. 
The private key is obtained earlier in the code with this line of code:

```
pin = (char *) getpass("Enter PIN: ");
rc = PKCS11_login(slot, 0, pin);
authkey = PKCS11_find_key(&certs[0]);
```

If it's necessary I can post the code on how I get the slot, but I don't think it's necessary for now.

I'm trying to validate the signature in PHP using this code:

```
function isOriginal() {
    $signature = base64_decode("HZwn2Zz4ir5Isvvo+fEj8IFydQs/tuW3I6HPzadHMIq+i5qCBURXqK/B5X1gYyoCPyHzgyY/zJI1skoFdKwPwx6ySEwLBZ5QTFsxp56jGi/UZgXu8X+jfvHfss89VhqcIxiZdklhZtlf5sMdJ045KbfvHDeAyfXj2C/3Nvk8IQMR+q3eUGAkiEZJIWpivp5WufrjFlsmKRdDm8j2szJPtIVipyj1AwIYkiAJOggC4JWd3LWn8C4bt84ys2CezFbc7BDckLe2IGBkaDMsCTr8PE0SP81npqHd9CyfvU4zd5LyXkBNZqz3QnAN19iI0b5EdUeJj3UQ83gmuugGy1088g==");
    $publicRSAKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy8Dbv8prpJ/0kKhlGeJYozo2t60EG8L0561g13R29LvMR5hyvGZlGJpmn65+A4xHXInJYiPuKzrKUnApeLZ+vw1HocOAZtWK0z3r26uA8kQYOKX9Qt/DbCdvsF9wF8gRK0ptx9M6R13NvBxvVQApfc9jB9nTzphOgM4JiEYvlV8FLhg9yZovMYd6Wwf3aoXK891VQxTr/kQYoq1Yp+68i6T4nNq7NWC+UNVjQHxNQMQMzU6lWCX8zyg3yH88OAQkUXIXKfQ+NkvYQ1cxaMoVPpY72+eVthKzpMeyHkBn7ciumk5qgLTEJAfWZpe4f4eFZj/Rc8Y8Jj2IS5kVPjUywQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";       

    $plaintext = "My secret message.";  

    $id = openssl_pkey_get_public(MY_PUB_CERT_IN_A_CONST_STR);

    echo (openssl_verify($plaintext, $signature, $id, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256) ? 'verified' : 'unverified'); 
}
```

This fails. I've also tried to use PHPSECLIB:

```
function isOriginal() {
    $signature = base64_decode("HZwn2Zz4ir5Isvvo+fEj8IFydQs/tuW3I6HPzadHMIq+i5qCBURXqK/B5X1gYyoCPyHzgyY/zJI1skoFdKwPwx6ySEwLBZ5QTFsxp56jGi/UZgXu8X+jfvHfss89VhqcIxiZdklhZtlf5sMdJ045KbfvHDeAyfXj2C/3Nvk8IQMR+q3eUGAkiEZJIWpivp5WufrjFlsmKRdDm8j2szJPtIVipyj1AwIYkiAJOggC4JWd3LWn8C4bt84ys2CezFbc7BDckLe2IGBkaDMsCTr8PE0SP81npqHd9CyfvU4zd5LyXkBNZqz3QnAN19iI0b5EdUeJj3UQ83gmuugGy1088g==");
    $publicRSAKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy8Dbv8prpJ/0kKhlGeJYozo2t60EG8L0561g13R29LvMR5hyvGZlGJpmn65+A4xHXInJYiPuKzrKUnApeLZ+vw1HocOAZtWK0z3r26uA8kQYOKX9Qt/DbCdvsF9wF8gRK0ptx9M6R13NvBxvVQApfc9jB9nTzphOgM4JiEYvlV8FLhg9yZovMYd6Wwf3aoXK891VQxTr/kQYoq1Yp+68i6T4nNq7NWC+UNVjQHxNQMQMzU6lWCX8zyg3yH88OAQkUXIXKfQ+NkvYQ1cxaMoVPpY72+eVthKzpMeyHkBn7ciumk5qgLTEJAfWZpe4f4eFZj/Rc8Y8Jj2IS5kVPjUywQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";        

    $rsa = new RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey($publicRSAKey);
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');

    $plaintext = "My secret message.";  

    echo ($rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'verified' : 'unverified');
}
```

with equal results. Does anyone have any clue why it fails? AFAIU I'm using the same algo in both C and PHP. 
Any help appreciated.

You might also wonder why I'm trying to do this and why I don't validate separately in PHP using PHP functions and C functions in C. It's because I want to sign messages and files with A3 tokens accessible only from .so files in C. AFAIU PHP doesn't have any functions to sign files using A3 tokens.

If there is any option to sign files using A3 tokens from PHP, I'd really want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For phpseclib do this before `$rsa->verify()`:

```
$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
```

To do this with X.509 certs...

```
$x509 = new \phpseclib\File\X509;
$x509->loadX509('...');
$rsa = $x509->getPublicKey();
```

Comment: Now I got another problem. I checked against RSA public key. Not using client's certiticate. Do you know how to do check with the client certificate  ?

Comment: I could load the public key that way. But then I got unverified... And I thought my code better and realized that It's probably not being encrypted with the token's private key, once I only need the RSA public key to check the signature... I think I better open another question as this already deviates too far from the original question.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira - you'd probably have to do `$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1)` again. But yah a new question might be more appropriate idk lol.